# Unity3D , Error GetItem(int 32)

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

i created 3 scripts for create an item , add item to list and show item.
When i'm trying get item to list , this error occurs.

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
charactersScript.GetItem (Int32 id)

the error is at line charactersScript.GetItem (Int32 id)
Here my scripts

itemdatabese for item class

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class itemDataBase : ScriptableObject
{    
    public int itemID;
    public int itemDamage;
    public string itemName;

    public itemDataBase(int _id, int _damage, string _name)
    {    
        itemID = _id;
        itemDamage = _damage;
        itemName = _name;
    }
}
```

technology script unlock for item and add to list

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class technologyScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int countID = 0;
    List<itemDataBase> item = new List<itemDataBase>();

    public void StoneSpear()
    {
        countID += 1;
        item.Add(new itemDataBase(countID, 7, "Stone Spear"));    
    }
}
```

and character script for show this item

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class charactersScript : MonoBehaviour
{  
    static public List<itemDataBase> _item;

    static public itemDataBase GetItem(int id)
    {  
        foreach (itemDataBase item in _item)
        {
            if (item.itemID == id)
            {
                return ScriptableObject.Instantiate(item) as itemDataBase;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void rightWeapon()
    {

        weaponID += 1;

        itemDataBase _item = GetItem(weaponID);
        if (_item != null)
        {
            Debug.Log(_item.id);
        }
    } 
}
```

is there any suggestion?

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
charactersScript.GetItem (Int32 id)

Comment: Maybe your List _item is empty or it doesn't contain a matching item and the function returns null.

Comment: if so stoneSpear function not working correctly. but i don't know how to check it adding item to list correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding `new itemDataBase()` to one instance of List in technologyScript and then in charactersScript you are trying to loop through a ***different*** list (`List<itemDataBase> _item`) which is never instantiated and is null and throws the exception. The `static` list doesn't just automatically share the values of the other list just because you declared it with the static keyword.

Set your `List<itemDataBase> item` to public.
Try this:

```
foreach (itemDataBase item in GetComponent<technologyScript>().item)
{
      if(item.itemID==id)
      {
          return ScriptableObject.Instantiate(item) as itemDataBase;
      }
}
```

This presumes that technologyScript is on the same gameobject as this script, if not then you will need GameObject.Find(correctObj)...

Comment: still not working. by your said , i need a function for load items from list item to list _item. 
 _item = new List<itemDataBase>();

  itemDataBase[] resources= Resources.LoadAll<itemDataBase>(@"itemDatabase");

  foreach(itemDataBase item in resources){
   
   if(!_item.Contains(item)){

    _item.Add(item);

   }
and now working. thanks your inspiration

Comment: @yatagac Nice. Please consider accepting it as the answer if it helped you find a solution and understand the problem.